# Java - modify compareTo method to sort integers from 1

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to sort an ArrayList of objects using of comparable interface:

```
public class Unit implements Comparable<Unit>{
    // attributes
    int position;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Unit other) {
        return Integer.compare(position, other.position);
    }
}
```

Now I sort the ArrayList using:

```
List<Unit> units = getAllUnits();
Collections.sort(units);
```

The  above will sort all the units starts from `position 0` but I want this to start from `position 1` because the default value of `position` is `zero`.

How can I modify the `compareTo` method?

Comment: Am I interpreting (this unclear question) correct: Do you want all the zeroes to be at the end?

Comment: Yes, I want all zeroes to be at the end.

Comment: so instead of low to high you want it to sort high to low? its unclear whats being asked

Comment: @chancea: No I only want the sort to start from 1 and I want all zeroes to be appear at the end.

Comment: @stsd: will there also be negative numbers?

Comment: @jlordo, no there is no negative position.

Comment: insert `if (this.position == 0) return 1;` before the other return.

Comment: @Ingo: position 0 should not be considered as position 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Using the information in your comment, that there will be no negative numbers,) you should be able to use this:

```
public int compareTo(Unit other) {
    if (position != other.position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (other.position == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        return Integer.compare(position, other.position);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

Update: It will also work for negative numbers, example output: `[-1, 1, 2, 0, 0]`